# Replacing old electrical work

Tags: receptacle, old-house, old-work

Bought an old house (1911) over the summer and I'm looking into making the upstairs more livable.

The upstairs is a converted attic, there are three rooms and a hallway and only three outlets in total (one being two prong), no outlets in one room and none in hallway. Looking into adding more outlets everywhere. I found the breaker that controls the upstairs outlets and lights, however, it also controls half of the lights on the main floor and a few of the outlets down there too so I can't shut it off.

I'm thinking figuring out where these upstairs wires link to the main floor to be able to rip out all the old wiring upstairs is gonna be very difficult. So I was thinking what I could do is run three new circuits up, one for each room and tap off one room to add two outlets to the hallway. Once that's all set up, I could turn off the old breaker, terminate the live wires for the old outlets and old lights and then turn the breaker back on so that the main floor is back on.

Wondering what people think of the plan and whether there are any better suggestions. Any advice would be awesome!! Thanks.

Comment: I dislike the "one circuit for each room" mentality.  Very often somebody makes a room a home-office, and they can't fit everything on 1 circuit, especially if a window A/C is involved!  Therefore I recommend **1 circuit *per wall***.  (within reason). That way a circuit in a shared wall is serving rooms on both sides of that wall, and you only have to run 1 cable down that wall.  So cable savings.  That gives each room access to at least 2 circuits.

Comment: We all have our preferences, and code does not dictate in this case. I like the lights on their own circuit, since then nobody can plug the heater or air-conditioner into the light circuit and leave you in the dark. Within reason (it gets expensive after 2 or 3 common colors), I also like to use color-coded-per-circuit receptacles when there are multiple circuits with receptacles in a room.

Comment: Never thought of that! Thanks for the suggestion. What are your thoughts on the process of terminating the old wires? Better to get a professional in to rip it all out? Or is in-wall termination in a box a fine solution?

Comment: Code doesn't require anything extreme re: removing old wiring.  If you're putting it permanently out of service, just postitively identify both ends of the cable and destroy both ends insofar as you can reach it.  Just make it obvious that it's abandoned wiring to the next guy who opens up the walls.  Don't allow a snipped-off cable to be energized, that's why it's vital to identify both ends and destroy both at once. If you throw it in trash, make it a big lump that's easy for the eddy current separator to pull out of the garbage stream. Copper is valuable.